# Keep braces when formatting compact if-else statements in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I like formatting my Java code in Eclipse. It keeps the code well indented and avoids problems with version systems. However, I can't find in Eclipse an option to maintain compact if-else statements and for loops with braces. I mean:

I get this one when I do the formatting:

```
if(a>6)
    a=7;
else
    a=8;
for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    a=a+i;
```

And I want this one:

```
if(a>6){
    a=7;
}
else{
    a=8;
}
for (int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    a=a+i;
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer for a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under "Preferences": Java > Editor > Save Actions

1) Check "Additional actions"

2) Click "Configure…"

3) Go to the "Code Style" tab

4) Check "Use blocks in if/while/for/do statements" and configure to your preferences

Comment: which flavour of eclipse you are using? In Indigo, it's under Java > Editor > Templates.

Comment: Good one! Thank you. I use Helios.

Comment: Glad it helped. rits: I might have been using Helios at that time.

Comment: @rits, I guess it's the same in Indigo and later. Isn't the templates part related with autogenerated code (getting the editor to write determined code when shorcut operations performed) instead of formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new format template here:

Menu Windows -> Preferences.
Java -> Code Style -> Formatter.